# Does the quantile() function in Pandas ignore NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, quantile

I have a dfAB

```
import pandas as pd
import random

A = [ random.randint(0,100) for i in range(10) ]
B = [ random.randint(0,100) for i in range(10) ]

dfAB = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': A, 'B': B })
dfAB
```

We can take the quantile function, because I want to know the 75th percentile of the columns:

```
dfAB.quantile(0.75)
```

But say now I put some NaNs in the dfAB and re-do the function, obviously its differnt:

```
dfAB.loc[5:8]=np.nan
dfAB.quantile(0.75)
```

Basically, when I calculated the mean of the dfAB, I passed skipna to ignore Na's as I didn't want them affecting my stats (I have quite a few in my code, on purpose, and obv making them zero doesn't help)

```
dfAB.mean(skipna=True)
```

Thus, what im getting at is whether/how the quantile function addresses NaN's?

Comment: Well, if you pass skipna=True, I guess it skips them.

Comment: If you not pass skipna=True , in mean , if it have nan , it will return nan

Comment: Don't ask us; we're biological units.  Try it and see what happens.  Load a df with half `NaN` values and play around for a few minutes.

Comment: side comment on the way you generate A, B.  you can just A = np.random.randint(100, size=10)

Comment: Docs didn't have a reference to skipnan for quantile function, that's why I asked.. 
DataFrame.quantile(q=0.5, axis=0, numeric_only=True, interpolation='linear')
@sacul kindly highlighted the correct comparator, which I didn't know existed, in np.nanpercentile
Thanks all

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, this appears to be the way that `pd.quantile` deals with `NaN` values. To illustrate, you can compare the results to `np.nanpercentile`, which explicitely *Computes the qth percentile of the data along the specified axis, **while ignoring nan values*** (quoted from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanpercentile.html#numpy.nanpercentile), my emphasis):

```
>>> dfAB
      A     B
0   5.0  10.0
1  43.0  67.0
2  86.0   2.0
3  61.0  83.0
4   2.0  27.0
5   NaN   NaN
6   NaN   NaN
7   NaN   NaN
8   NaN   NaN
9  27.0  70.0

>>> dfAB.quantile(0.75)
A    56.50
B    69.25
Name: 0.75, dtype: float64

>>> np.nanpercentile(dfAB, 75, axis=0)
array([56.5 , 69.25])
```

And see that they are equivalent

Comment: For Pandas v2.0 and up the default for numeric_only is False. See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html). I expect this will change the output of the answer here.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**.  `pd.quantile()` will **ignore NaN values** when calculating the quantile.

To prove this, we can compare it with [`np.nanquantile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanquantile.html), which *compute the qth quantile of the data along the specified axis, while **ignoring nan values**[[source]](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanquantile.html)* .

```
>>> random.seed(7)
>>> A = [ random.randint(0,100) for i in range(10) ]
>>> B = [ random.randint(0,100) for i in range(10) ]
>>> dfAB = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B})
>>> dfAB.loc[5:8]=np.nan

>>> dfAB
      A     B
0  41.0   7.0
1  19.0  64.0
2  50.0  27.0
3  83.0   4.0
4   6.0  11.0
5   NaN   NaN
6   NaN   NaN
7   NaN   NaN
8   NaN   NaN
9  74.0  11.0

>>> dfAB.quantile(0.75)
A    68.0
B    23.0
Name: 0.75, dtype: float64

>>> np.nanquantile(dfAB, 0.75, axis=0)
array([68.  23.])
```